Blazor 2-way binding inconsistency
It appears that when I pass a class as a two-way parameter, that if I replace/update the entire instance of the class that the two-way binding is not activated. The return event to update the source of the parameter is only executed when a property of the class is updated.
For example: my parent component has the following
<DataSourceDatabase @bind-DataSource="@DataSource"
                    IsComponentDisabled="false">
</DataSourceDatabase>

My child component has the following parameters set:
    partial class DataSourceDatabase
    {
        [Parameter] public DataSourceModel DataSource { get; set; } = new();
        [Parameter] public EventCallback<DataSourceModel> DataSourceChanged { get; set; } 

I have a server method which will potentially change/set several attributes of the DataSource instance.
When I call that method and set the DataSource to the response this way, the two-way binding will not fire, meaning the instance of the DataSource in the parent component will not get updated:
var validateResponse = await PipelineServer.ValidateSource(request);
if (validateResponse.Success)
{
   DataSource = validateResponse.Data
}

However, if I do the following, then the two-way binding will work and the instance in the parent component will get updated with the current value:
var validateResponse = await PipelineServer.ValidateSource(request);
if (validateResponse.Success)
{
   DataSource.DefaultSchema = validateResponse.Data.DefaultSchema;
...
}

My question is, am I missing something?
If not, I hope this helps others

A binding from a parent to a child will only be applied to the child if the parent renders.  This will either be as part of the component lifecycle [such as when OnParametersChanged{Async} is called], or as part of a UI event [such as a button click], or when StateHasChanged is called manually.  Your code doesn't show where you are updating the class instance, so it's impossible to answer the question as is.

My situation is that either component may change different properties of DataSource. The way they are organized is that the parent handles properties common to all types of data sources and then there are multiple versions of the child component each which handle specific properties of the child. One child may handle a data source that is a database, another a file, another an S3 bucket, etc.
